# Why does this subarray act as a copy, not a view?

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider the 6x4 np array `z` shown below.  I find a subarray, `z0`, which has the first 3 columns of all rows of `z` that end in `0`.

```
import numpy as np

z = np.array(
  [[ 0,  2, -4,  0],
   [ 3, -6,  1,  0],
   [-1,  6,  1,  1],
   [ 5, -3, -2,  1],
   [ 6,  3,  2,  0],
   [-1,  6,  1,  1]])


z0 = z[z[:, -1] == 0, :-1] 

# the result is:
# z0 = [[ 0,  2, -4],
#       [ 3, -6,  1],
#       [ 6,  3,  2]]
```

Then I change a value in the subarray:

```
z0[0,0] = 99

# the result is:
# z0 = [[99,  2, -4],
#       [ 3, -6,  1],
#       [ 6,  3,  2]]
```

**QUESTION:**  Why does this subarray act as a COPY, not a VIEW?  I'd like the change in `z0` to show up in `z`, but it doesn't.    (I understand there is a `view` method that could force the issue, but I'm not sure how to implement it properly.

Comment: The first dimension index, `z[:, -1] == 0`, is a bolean array.  This does `advanced indexing`, and makes a copy.  There's no way of using a slice to describe the rows you want `[0,1,4]`. (The `view` method won't help here.)

Comment: So, perhaps the view vs copy isn't even needed.   Is there a way to start with z, then multiply all cell values by -1  for rows that end with 0?   Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: `z[z[:, -1] == 0,:] *= -1`. Set `=` and `+=` kinds of operators work even with advanced indexing.  Just don't try chained indexing, e.g. `z[[0,1,4]][0,0] = 10`, which is just a oneline version of your `z0`.